# Ubuntu14.04 install apache2 / php fail

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, apache2, php

I am trying to install apache and php on my ubuntu14.04 via

`$ sudo apt-get install apache2 php5`

There are some errors like bellows. Does someone know how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security/main apache2 amd64 2.4.10-1ubuntu1.1 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-bin_2.4.10-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by removing the bellow line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic-security main
```